# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on HDD of a computer with Secure Boot that has Win10 on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to install 16.04 on the HDD. Right now, HDD is never used. On the SSD, I have Win10 which I need for my school-related software. What I want are:

- Install Ubuntu 16.04 on HDD.
- Keep Secure Boot on.
- Do not mess up the SSD part.

I thought of basically installing 16.04 to HDD but I don't know how to have a dual-boot selector (such as grub) and heard that it will try to install itself on Win10 part.

Comment: Is the hdd seen as device sda (from install media/Try Ubuntu...)?  Can you remove the SDD during the install?  Are you running any proprietary hardware like Nvidia (may be a problem if you try to use proprietary drivers). The install will put the root where you select, but the (grub/shim) bootloader(s) go to the EFI on sda, regardless of what you select.

Comment: @ubfan1 I don't know the meaning of many terms here. I can try the Try Ubuntu feature to check if HDD is seen as sda. I don't think I can remove the SSD. Laptop has GTX graphics card but uses motherboard's graphics card by default and switches only when necessary. What is EFI sda? Do I need grub? Can't I just choose from UEFI what device to boot?

Comment: Assuming the SDD has an EFI  partition, and boots from it, you should set up another EFI partition on the hdd so it can boot under UEFI (so you don't have to touch the SDD's EFI). Then you can choose which device to boot.

Comment: @ubfan1 So all I have to do is to install Ubuntu on HDD with UEFI mode rather than legacy mode and then install grub?

Comment: Right, use UEFI mode (boot the install median UEFI mode).  The install should put grub/shim into the EFI partition of sda.   Ensure Windows hibernation is off before trying this.  Grub should also pick up the Windows and offer it as a boot option, even if secure boot is on.

Comment: `Ensure Windows hibernation is off before trying this` ...

Why? Also, if sda is SSD where Win10 lies, can I change it so grub installs on HDD?

Comment: With hibernation off, the installer will see it, and add it to the grub choices.  If the SSD is device sda, then either remove it for the install (so hdd becomes sda), or manually copy the whole sdd EFI partition to the hdd EFI partition with some additional tweaking maybe necessary.  If you can remove the SSD, that's easiest.  the installer will ignore where you tell it to put grub ;^(

Comment: @ubfan1 I see. Do I need to physically remove the SSD? Is there a way to shut it down from BIOS?

Comment: Moving my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install will put the root where you select, but the (grub/shim) bootloader(s) go to the EFI on sda, regardless of what you select.

Assuming the SDD is UEFI mode, has an EFI partition, and boots from it, you should set up another EFI partition on the hdd so it can boot under UEFI (so you don't have to touch the SDD's EFI). Then you can choose which device to boot.  (boot the install median UEFI mode). The install should put grub/shim into the EFI partition of sda. Ensure Windows hibernation is off before trying this. Grub should also pick up the Windows and offer it as a boot option, even if secure boot is on.  If hibernation is on, Grub might not be able to mount/see Windows, and not include it in the boot choices.

If the SSD is device sda, then either remove it for the install (so hdd becomes sda), or manually copy the whole sdd EFI partition to the hdd EFI partition with some additional tweaking maybe necessary. If you can remove the SSD, that's easiest. the installer will ignore where you tell it to put grub ;^(   I've not seen the suggestion to shut down temporarily unwanted disks from the BIOS, but that probably would work too.  The worst that could happen is the SDD is seen anyway, and gets an /EFI/ubuntu directory, and maybe a rename of
/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.